# Unity 2D extendable rope

Tags: unity, assets, rope-physics

I need the player to be able to drag a game object that is connected to a rope, and for the rope to extend with it. I have purchased Ultimate Rope Editor, but it looks like it was meant for Unity 3D, and I can't get it to work. Any solutions, or am i out of luck?

Comment: have you found the solution yet? Since i am having the same problem:(